# How to say 'I feel pain in my back'?

Tags: traducción

I thought about:

> Siento un dolor en mi espalda

Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You usually say:

> Me duele la espalda

Comment: Puede decirse '  cuando estaba en el mercado ' Mi Pueblo' mi espalda comienzó a doler' ?

Comment: Cuando estaba en el mercado la espalda empezó a dolerme

Answer (score 2):

Yes, many alternatives.        "me duele la espalda"       "No aguanto la espalda"        "Tengo un dolor en la espalda"   Me lastimé la espalda" estoy dolido de la espalda"...